# Python parse xml and save 100 request

Tags: python, xml, request

I have 10000 SKU in products.xml file. How can I make for example 300 SKU (300 request), store data into xml and start again from 301 SKU. I would like to split 10000 SKUs into smaller pieces, write to multiple files because the loop cannot execute in that long.

````
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import time
from time import sleep


tree = ET.parse('products.xml')

root = tree.getroot()


for id in root.iter('SKU'):
        sku = id.text
        
        
        response = requests.get('http://example.com/Items&ID='+sku)
        
        with open("_Temp.xml", "w") as f:
                f.write(response.text)
        print(response.text) ```
  

'''
````

Comment: "the loop cannot execute in that long" What?

Comment: I meant that the server probably cuts the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for i, group in enumerate(zip_longest(*[iter(root.iter('SKU'))] * 300), 1):
    with open(f"{i}_Temp.xml", "w") as f:
        for id in group:
            if group != None:
                sku = id.text
                response = requests.get(f'http://example.com/Items&ID={sku}')
                f.write(response.text)
```